# How is the bitcoin block header data padded for SHA256 hashing?

Tags: sha256, bitcoin

I see that a block contains 80 bytes. SHA256 expects integral multiples of 64 bytes as input. How are the remaining 48 bytes calculated?

Answer (score 2):

According to section 5.1.1 of [FIPS-180-4](https://dx.doi.org/10.6028/NIST.FIPS.180-4), SHA-256 messages are padded with a binary 1, followed by a number of 0s, and finally a 64-bit binary representation of the length of the message:

```
Suppose that the length of the message, M, is  bits. Append the bit "1" to the
end of the message, followed by k zero bits, where k is the smallest, non-
negative solution to the equation  + 1 + k ≡ 448 mod 512. Then append the 64-bit
block that is equal to the number  expressed using a binary representation.
```

This is not specific to Bitcoin, and any correct SHA-256 [implementation](https://github.com/B-Con/crypto-algorithms/blob/master/sha256.c#L114) will do this. For Bitcoin, a remaining 48 bytes of padding would be a [single binary 1](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/47149/54184), a bunch of 0s, and the binary representation of the number 640 (80 bytes in bits). In binary, the remaining 48 bytes would be:

```
1 00...00 0110 0100 0000
```

Note that the SHA family of functions represent binary in [big-endian](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/ien/ien137.txt) format.